# C# Crypter with .NET payload runtime error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, fork

I am currently developing a crypter for educational purposes, but I am having a runtime error.
This runtime error only occurs on a certain payloads, which require any dependencies like dll files or in particular the .NET Framework, and redirects me to this Microsoft help page (in case, we require .NET):
https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/2715633.

The crypter is pretty simple, it encrypts/decrypts the payload with AES in memory and runs it from there.
This approach works, except for payloads, that require dependencies (everything thats not a standalone .exe does not work).

So my questions:
1. are dependencies loaded? and if not, why ?
2. when do programs load such dependencies, like .NET ?
3. are there any restrictions for running code from memory, that could cause this error?

In the case of requiring a dll, it also won't help to just put the dll file in same folder as the crypted payload (see question 1).
When .Net is required, the OS should somehow handle this right (question 2) ?

I would be happy, if you can give me any details, that help me with solving my problem :)

Comment: Any program compiled in Visual Studio Requires the Net Library  The net library uses DLL which are interfaces to the Operating System.  On PC's that don;t have Net (or not the same version or net) You must install the software like any commercial purchased software.  Visual Studio has a publish option that create an installation folder(s) with setup.exe in the root folder. You must run setup.exe on the deploy PC for the program to run.  Setup will create sortcuts and install in the window folder any dlls that are needed to run application that currently are missing (or are different versions).

Comment: The thing is, running the program without the crypter works, so the .NET Framework is installed and correctly bound in, but with the crypter, this doesnt work anymore. So i think it must have something to do with the execution in memory.

Comment: The Net Library is a lot of different Dlls.  Each Library like System.Data has its own dll.  Only the dlls that are required are installed.  It just means another application install some dlls but not the Encryption Library dll.

Comment: Okay, so where exactly do you think it breaks ? The missing dll's when executing in memory ? Because the payload being run normally is working.

Comment: There is a call from the c# executable to a Windows dll (installed with application) that is missing or is wrong version.  I would use the menu Build : Publish.  Select build to CD (which can be on any type file system).  When done run the setup.exe on deploy PC like any purchased software.